# BadRequestException: You must use the customer-specific endpoint

Tags: aws-sdk

When trying to create a job with MediaConvert I provide the customer endpoint but I'm still getting the error saying it's needed.
Here's an example of my code:

```js
import { MediaConvertClient, CreateJobCommand } from '@aws-sdk/client-mediaconvert';
const mediaConvertClient = new MediaConvertClient({
    region: 'us-east-2',
    credentials: {
      accessKeyId,
      secretAccessKey
    },
    role: MY_ROLE,
    settings: {
      endpoint: MY_ENDPOINT
    }
  });

  const createJobCommand = new CreateJobCommand({
    Input: { Bucket, Key },
    Output: { Bucket, Key },
    OutputFormat: 'mp4'
  });

  mediaConvertClient.send(createJobCommand, (err, data) => {
    if (err) {
      console.error(err);
    } else {
      console.log(data);
    }
  });
```

then when I run it I get:
`BadRequestException: You must use the customer-specific endpoint 'my-end-point' for this operation`

Answer (score 1):

after much digging the solution is the following:

```js
const mediaConvertClient = new MediaConvertClient({
    region: 'us-east-2',
    credentials: { accessKeyId, secretAccessKey },
    endpoint: process.env.ENDPOINT
  });
```